# Неотображаемая пагинация

Tags: php, html, wordpress, веб-программирование, pagination

Действую согласно [Вывод постов](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIDId7lej80&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=5&t=912s)

Есть файл `blog.php`

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Myblogpage
*/
?>

<?php get_header('third'); ?>


   <!-- Content
   ================================================== -->
   <div class="content-outer">

      <div id="page-content" class="row">

         <div id="primary" class="eight columns">

            <?php /*if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); */ $query = new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'post']);
            /*print_r($query);*/
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                ?>
            
            <article class="post">

               <div class="entry-header cf">

                  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <?php the_category($separator=' / ', '') ?>
                     <!--
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     -->
                     </span>

                  </p>

               </div>

               <div class="post-thumb">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumb') ?><!--<img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-01.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image">--></a>
               </div>

               <div class="post-content">

                  <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>

               </div>

            </article> <!-- post end -->
            
            <?php } 
            
            the_posts_pagination();
            
            ?>
            
            <!--<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>-->

            <!-- Pagination -->
            <!--
            <nav class="col full pagination">
                  <ul>
                  <li><span class="page-numbers prev inactive">Prev</span></li>
                      <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">5</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">6</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">7</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">8</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">9</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers next">Next</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
            -->
         </div> <!-- Primary End-->

         <div id="secondary" class="four columns end">

            <!--
            <aside id="sidebar">

               <div class="widget widget_search">
                  <h5>Search</h5>
                  <form action="#">

                     <input class="text-search" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search here...') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search here...'; }" value="Search here...">
                     <input type="submit" class="submit-search" value="">

                  </form>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_text">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Text Widget</h5>
                  <div class="textwidget">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
                  Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum,
                  nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus
                  a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. </div>
                 </div>

               <div class="widget widget_categories">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Categories</h5>
                  <ul class="link-list cf">
                     <li><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Other Stuff</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_tag_cloud">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Tags</h5>
                  <div class="tagcloud cf">
                     <a href="#">drupal</a>
                     <a href="#">joomla</a>
                     <a href="#">ghost</a>
                     <a href="#">wordpress</a>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_photostream">
                  <h5>Photostream</h5>
                  <ul class="photostream cf">
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

            </aside>
            -->
            
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

         </div> <!-- Secondary End-->

      </div>

   </div> <!-- Content End-->

   <!-- Tweets Section
   ================================================== -->
   <section id="tweets">

      <div class="row">

         <div class="tweeter-icon align-center">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
         </div>

         <ul id="twitter" class="align-center">
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">2 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            <!--
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">3 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            -->
         </ul>

         <p class="align-center"><a href="#" class="button">Follow us</a></p>

      </div>

   </section> <!-- Tweets Section End-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

файл functions.php

```html
<?php

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_theme');
add_action('wp_footer', 'scripts_theme');
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_register_nav_menu');
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_widgets' );

function register_my_widgets(){

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Right Sidebar',
        'id'            => "right_sidebar",
        'description'   => 'Описание нашего сайдбара',
        'class'         => '',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => "</li>\n",
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => "</h2>\n",
        'before_sidebar' => '', // WP 5.6
        'after_sidebar'  => '', // WP 5.6
    ) );
}

function theme_register_nav_menu()
{
    register_nav_menu('top', 'Меню в шапке');
    register_nav_menu('bottom', 'Меню в подвале');
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post'));
    add_image_size('post_thumb', 1300, 500, true);

    // удаляет H2 из шаблона пагинации
    
    add_filter('navigation_markup_template', 'my_navigation_template', 2, 1 );
    function my_navigation_template( $template, $class ){*/
        /*
        Вид базового шаблона:
        <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
            <div class="nav-links">%3$s</div>
        </nav>
        */
        
    
        return '
        <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-links">%3$s</div>
        </nav>
        ';
        
    }

    // выводим пагинацию
    
    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'end_size' => 1,
    ) );
        
}

function style_theme()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('default', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/default.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('layout', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/layout.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('media-queries', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/media-queries.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/modernizr.js');
}

function scripts_theme()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('localjquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.min.js');
    /*echo "<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>')</script>";*/
    wp_enqueue_script('jquerymigrate121', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('doubletaptogo', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/doubletaptogo.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('init', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/init.js');
}


?>
```

настройки пагинации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в результате получаю страницу без пагинации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ка добиться отображения пагинации?

Отредактировал файл blog.php (копипастом) и получил следующую ошибку

```html
    <?php
    /*
    Template Name: Myblogpage
    */
    ?>

    <?php get_header('third'); ?>


       <!-- Content
       ================================================== -->
       <div class="content-outer">

          <div id="page-content" class="row">

             <div id="primary" class="eight columns">

                <?php /*if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post();  $query = new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'post']);*/
                            
                $current = absint(
                  max(
                    1,
                    get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : get_query_var( 'page' )
                  )
                );
                $posts_per_page = 2;
                $query          = new WP_Query(
                  [
                    'post_type'      => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
                    'paged'          => $current,
                  ]
                );          
                
                /*print_r($query);*/
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    ?>
                
                <article class="post">

                   <div class="entry-header cf">

                      <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>

                      <p class="post-meta">

                         <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
                         /
                         <span class="categories">
                         <?php the_category($separator=' / ', '') ?>
                         <!--
                         <a href="#">Design</a> /
                         <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                         <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                         -->
                         </span>

                      </p>

                   </div>

                   <div class="post-thumb">
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumb') ?><!--<img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-01.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image">--></a>
                   </div>

                   <div class="post-content">

                      <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>

                   </div>

                </article> <!-- post end -->
                
                <?php } 
                
                echo wp_kses_post(
                    paginate_links(
                    [
                        'total'   => $query->max_num_pages,
                        'current' => $current,
                    ]
                )
                );          
                
                /*the_posts_pagination();*/
                
                ?>
                
                <!--<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>-->

                <!-- Pagination -->
                <!--
                <nav class="col full pagination">
                      <ul>
                      <li><span class="page-numbers prev inactive">Prev</span></li>
                          <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">4</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">5</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">6</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">7</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">8</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">9</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers next">Next</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </nav>
                -->
             </div> <!-- Primary End-->

             <div id="secondary" class="four columns end">

                <!--
                <aside id="sidebar">

                   <div class="widget widget_search">
                      <h5>Search</h5>
                      <form action="#">

                         <input class="text-search" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search here...') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search here...'; }" value="Search here...">
                         <input type="submit" class="submit-search" value="">

                      </form>
                   </div>

                   <div class="widget widget_text">
                      <h5 class="widget-title">Text Widget</h5>
                      <div class="textwidget">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
                      Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum,
                      nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus
                      a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. </div>
                     </div>

                   <div class="widget widget_categories">
                      <h5 class="widget-title">Categories</h5>
                      <ul class="link-list cf">
                         <li><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Other Stuff</a></li>
                      </ul>
                   </div>

                   <div class="widget widget_tag_cloud">
                      <h5 class="widget-title">Tags</h5>
                      <div class="tagcloud cf">
                         <a href="#">drupal</a>
                         <a href="#">joomla</a>
                         <a href="#">ghost</a>
                         <a href="#">wordpress</a>
                      </div>
                   </div>

                   <div class="widget widget_photostream">
                      <h5>Photostream</h5>
                      <ul class="photostream cf">
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>

                </aside>
                -->
                
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

             </div> <!-- Secondary End-->

          </div>

       </div> <!-- Content End-->

       <!-- Tweets Section
       ================================================== -->
       <section id="tweets">

          <div class="row">

             <div class="tweeter-icon align-center">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
             </div>

             <ul id="twitter" class="align-center">
                <li>
                   <span>
                   This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
                   Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
                   <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
                   </span>
                   <b><a href="#">2 Days Ago</a></b>
                </li>
                <!--
                <li>
                   <span>
                   This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
                   Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
                   <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
                   </span>
                   <b><a href="#">3 Days Ago</a></b>
                </li>
                -->
             </ul>

             <p class="align-center"><a href="#" class="button">Follow us</a></p>

          </div>

       </section> <!-- Tweets Section End-->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Что за функция wp_kses_post (см. https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/)?
2. В чем ошибка?

Comment: [https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/](https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/)

Comment: @Simon отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Прекрасно) Но я Вам удивляюсь, Вам не лень писать огромные простыни вопросы, но почему-то Вы даже не пытаетесь поискать ответ самостоятельно, прекрасно же гуглится. 1. Ссылка на документацию [wp_kses_post()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_kses_post). 2. Для того чтобы увидеть ошибку, включите [дебаг](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Comment: Возможно что ошибка в functions.php там где Вы закрываете комментарий `function my_navigation_template( $template, $class ){*/` <-- не вижу чтобы Вы его где-то открывали. Это если речь о критической ошибке которая возникла.

Comment: @Simon вы правы.